# How to set a mouseListener that the table could clicked only once?

Tags: java, swing, jtable, mouseevent, double-click

I have coded this Listener:

```
        playlistTable.addMouseListener(new MouseAdapter() {

        private boolean ignoreDoubleClicks = false;

        public void mouseClicked(MouseEvent e) {
            if (e.getClickCount() == 2 && !ignoreDoubleClicks) {
                this.ignoreDoubleClicks  = true;
                System.out.println(ignoreDoubleClicks);
                JTable target = (JTable)e.getSource();
                int row = target.getSelectedRow();

                videoTableModel = new VideoTableModel(playlistService.getMoviesOfPlaylist(row));
                target.setModel(videoTableModel);
                //TODO enables the table
                //movieTable.setEnabled(false);

                createPlaylist.setEnabled(false);
                setButtonIcon("icons\\playlist_grau.png", createPlaylist, "createPlaylist");

                removePlaylist.setEnabled(false);
                setButtonIcon("icons\\bin_grau.png", removePlaylist, "removePlaylist");

                algoButton.setEnabled(false);
                setButtonIcon("icons\\glyphicons_137_cogwheels_grau.png", algoButton, "algoButton");

                //                  playlistTable.setEnabled(false);

                revalidate();
            }
        }
    });
```

However, when I FIRST double click the playlist I get the movies. When I go back with another button and double click AGAIN on the playlisttable, it is not clickable anymore. Why?

**UPDATE**

The problem is  `this.ignoreDoubleClicks  = true;`
However, why it is not set to false?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

On the first double click mouse event, you set `this.ignoreDoubleClicks  = true` and I do not see any code that would reset it back to `false`. As all code seems wrapped into `if` statement that checks if `!this.ignoreDoubleClicks`, setting it to true locks the listener permanently. The left side of the condition (`e.getClickCount() == 2`) may or may not evaluate to true, does not matter anyway as the right side is `false` and the operator is the logical *and* `(&&).`

Comment: what would you recommend against this behaviour?

Comment: This depends on that is the goal and idea of this listener. Set the flag back to false when you want it to start responding again.